# Finding the basis of Row A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> True or false: If $B$ is any echelon form of matrix $A$, and if $B$
>   has three nonzero rows, then the first three rows of $A$ form a basis
>   for Row $A$.
>
> Solution: False. Row operations may change the linear dependence
>   relations among the rows of a matrix.

I thought that to find the basis for a row space, we would need to put it in row echelon form, which would involve row operations. If it's in row echelon form, wouldn't the three nonzero rows be at the top and the zero rows at the bottom, and thus be able to conclude that the statement is true

Comment: Read the statement again. The claim is that the first three rows of $A$, not of its rref, form a basis for the row space.

Comment: The 3 non zero rows of B form a basis for the row space of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row operations of course change the linear dependence relations between the rows; on the other hand, they never change the row space.

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and let $F$ be an invertible $m\times m$ matrix. Then
$$
\operatorname{Row}(A)=\operatorname{Row}(FA)
$$
Indeed, any element of $\operatorname{Row}(A)$ can be seen as $rA$ where $r$ is an $1\times m$ matrix. Since
$$
rA=(rF^{-1})FA,
$$
we see that $rA\in\operatorname{Row}(FA)$. The converse is similar:
$$
r(FA)=(rF)A\in\operatorname{Row}(A).
$$

A fundamental fact about row reduction is that a row reduced form $B$ of the matrix $A$ can be obtained by successively premultiplying $A$ by a suitable invertible matrix; so, at the end, $B=FA$ for some invertible matrix $F$.

Since the nonzero rows in a reduced echelon form are linearly independent and their number is the rank of the matrix, they form a basis for the row space.